# how to resume download in wget which is integrated with firefox via flashgot

Tags: firefox, suspend, downloads, wget, firefox-extensions

I use `wget` as a downloader. It is an excellent, outstanding application. I integrated it with Firefox using Flashgot.

How can I resume a download which was stopped by a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key press or a shutdown in this configuration of wget?

Comment: Out of question's scope but related. Have you tried Downloadthem all extension ? You dont need anything else.

Comment: If you mean 'Downthemall', then i tried it. It is nothing compared to wget.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I does not need any other download manager if i could pause and resume download

You started a file download in `wget` using `flashgot` plugin. As `wget` didn't remember last activity (and you are not from terminal and no bash `history`) normally you can't resume the download unless you provide a correct URI with -c in `wget`.

**case 1: Download cancel by <kbd>Ctrl C</kbd>**
Open with a text editor `/tmp/flashgot.*******.default/flashgot-*.fgt`
At the end of file you can see like

> "wget" --trust-server-names -c -O jre-7u21-linux-x64.rpm --directory-prefix=/home/totti/Downloads --referer=http://java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp\?locale=en  --load-cookies=/tmp/flashgot.7gavixy1.default/cookies --header=Cookie:s_vi=[CS]v1\|28BA8A90050109CA-6000011540153427[CE]\;\   --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0\ (X11\;\ Ubuntu\;\ Linux\ i686\;\ rv:16.0)\ Gecko/20100101\ Firefox/16.0 http://sdlc-esd.sun.com/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u21-b11/jre-7u21-linux-x64.rpm\?AuthParam=1366627766_80a413ae29c4b4d2e12ac7e334d61847\&GroupName=JSC\&FilePath=/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u21-b11/jre-7u21-linux-x64.rpm\&File=jre-7u21-linux-x64.rpm\&BHost=javadl.sun.com

either copy the whole parameter and pass it to  `wget` as
`wget --trust-server-names -c -O jre-7u21-linux-x64.rpm --directory-prefix=/home/totti/Downloads --referer=http://java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp\?locale=en  --load-cookies=/tmp/flashgot.7gavixy1.default/cookies --header=Cookie:s_vi=\[CS\]v1\|28BA8A90050109CA-6000011540153427\[CE\]\;\   --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0\ \(X11\;\ Ubuntu\;\ Linux\ i686\;\ rv:16.0\)\ Gecko/20100101\ Firefox/16.0 http://sdlc-esd.sun.com/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u21-b11/jre-7u21-linux-x64.rpm\?AuthParam=1366627766_80a413ae29c4b4d2e12ac7e334d61847\&GroupName=JSC\&FilePath=/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u21-b11/jre-7u21-linux-x64.rpm\&File=jre-7u21-linux-x64.rpm\&BHost=javadl.sun.com`
or just use `wget -c URI`

**case 2: Shutdown**
This is a bad thing as `/tmp` is cleared every shutdown. You have to find the URI manually. Another option is, before start downloading change temp dir for `flashgot` from preference -> advanced -> temp directory to a persistent folder (say ~/tmp).

**Updates:**
403 forbidden error
Because some URI are dynamically generated. So after some time it expire(after closing connection to the site). In such cases you have to obtain a new URI and download can be resumed using `wget -c URI`. Some cases the file name are also dynamic (or no file name at all), so `-o filenameofexistingfile` option is also needed.
Note that wget is a download manager not a video downloader. So use of a video downloader such as `flareget` `JDownloader` or plugin for your browser such as `savefromnet`, video download helper is prefered. Because they automate the process of obtaining new URI from the URL. See question *how to download youtube video* (search) for easyly download videos.

Comment: It perfectly worked for me. I have been seeking for this answer for two months. Thank you very much..  Can i clarify one more doubt with your help? ie; Why can't i use wget's command line arguments which was taken by the command :    `xargs -0 echo < /proc/<pid_of_wget>/cmdline`

Comment: Also, why ther are `flashgot-1.fgt`, `flashgot-2.fgt`, `flashgot-3.fgt`, etc in that folder??

Comment: One more..I changed the tmp folder as you suggested. But some times it shows: `ERROR 403: Forbidden` (usually after a restart)

Comment: Comment 1: Why u can't use ? question not clear. May be the URI contain special char that interfere with terminal.

Comment: Comment 2: flashgot-1.fgt for 1'st download by flashgot, flashgot-2.fgt is the 2nd. So the last one will be the one u want. Search ffrom last.

Comment: Comment 3: Changed to where?. Is u have permission on that folder?

Comment: I changed the /tmp folder to /home/aliyans/Downloads/wget_resume_fgt. But the command inside `flashgot-x.fgt` is not working after a restart(especially in the case of downloading from flash video based sites-youtube, metacafe, etc). The folder "wget_resume_fgt" is in my home, so i have full read-write access permission on it.

Comment: Updated. See answer.

Comment: Ok, I completely understand that. But, If i need to resume download, I should go to browser and select the URI through Flashgot or other add-on; right? Then i will try other download managers..Anyway, thanks for the response..

Comment: yaa. To automate the process of obtain valid URI it is preferred to use such video down loader (Only in the case of dynamic URI)

Comment: would the -c option still work if it was initially ran with the -r option?

Comment: expected to work with that @bubakazouba

Answer (score 8):

Wget can resume downloading partially-downloaded files with `-c` option. `Flashgot` by default calls `wget` with `-c` option so it's already enabled. You can check it in `System Monitor` while `wget` is downloading:

[image]

Wget will only be able to resume download if the server you're downloading form supports it and partially-downloaded file resides in the same directory where `wget` is downloading. For more details on this:

```
man wget
```

For URL list support checkout this article: [Make Wget cater to your needs](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/59457)

On a side note, I will suggest you to give a try to [Download Them All](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/). It has all the features you can ask for in a download manager.

Comment: 1.I don't like to use DTA, because i had already used it. In my opinion wget is the best. I have installed many GUIs for wget including gwget. None of them are up to the mark.

Comment: 2. I can resume my download if i started wget my own by starting a terminal and type the commands(Whenever i need to resume, just re-enter those line in terminal). But, in the above situation, i don't know  the URL associated with it and argument used.